# Editing a question with hyperlinks

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, hyperlinks

With less than 10 rep one can only post 2 hyperlinks.
So when I post an answer for example with some url it gets edited to have clickable links by someone with higher rep, which is fine.

Then if I need to edit my answer with more relevant stuff (not necessarily links) I'm rejected because the post already contains more than 2 links.

Is there a way to solve this problem (except waiting to have more than 10 rep)?

EDIT:
Community wiki doesn't get you points and they usually require more than 2 links.

Comment: I'd almost call this a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: Change the links back to non click-able so that you can post your edit.

Not sure if this needs to be fixed for three reasons:

- One vote gives you 10 rep, so if a high rep user edits your answer, then my guess is multiple people have seen it and hopefully someone would have given it a single vote if the answer is decent.
- Many answers (especially good ones) don't need links, so many users will get to 10 rep before they even post a link.
- A fix would be difficult.

Comment: @jzd: You forget about community wiki. You get no rep and the answers usually need many links.

Comment: oh and I forgot to say 10 rep is still not enough to add links. Needs to be > 10

Comment: @repecmps, you start at one rep, so one upvote on an answer will put you >10

Comment: @jzd: sorry that's not true. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/3956/repecmps

Comment: @repecmps, sorry that is true.  One up vote on an answer is 10 points and you start at one.  You got to 10 by one question vote (5) and two suggested edits(4 total) plus your beginning rep of 1.

Comment: oh right. That was confusing, thanks. Question stands though.